# Persistent cache in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching

I need a cache layer for my web app which stores gigabytes data in it, I found some options like Asp.net Cache, or Singleton approach to store my data in it, but as you know these options I mentioned already will be reset when application recycles ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then your going to have to look at solutions like Windows Server AppFabric Caching

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Is it durable? I mean persistent?

Comment: Yes.  AppFabric stores it's cache in XML, SQL Server or a custom provider.  It's out of process from the IIS pool.

Comment: In XML?
Isn't it in memory cache?

Comment: It's in memory but needs to persist it somewhere.  It's not an add-on you just slap on a project.  You would need to be thinking about it from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like Dache, a natively .NET distributed caching system. The whole idea of persisting data beyond application lifecycle is to have the data held **out-of-process** which typically means running on a different server. That way, when you reboot your app/server the data remains.